# ArcObjects Load features that don't exist

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#

I'm trying to write a method in ArcObjects .NET that will load features from a file GDB into another geodatabase but only if they don't otherwise exist.  Records are considered existing if there is a matching GlobalID.

Without looping through record by record and setting up a query for each record, is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Did you try loading two Dictionaries where key is global ID and value is objectID, then make a list of ObjectIDs for keys are present in one, but not the other, then create two cursors, one with [IFeatureClass.GetFeatures](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureClass_GetFeatures.htm) and another with [IFeatureClass.Insert](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IFeatureClass_Insert.htm).  Loop through each feature from the first cursor, inserting into the second cursor?

Comment: Yeah that's my "long" method.  I was wondering if there was a simpler approach.

Comment: Doing that shouldn't require "looping through record by record and setting up a query for each record".

Comment: Did you try to concatenate all GlobalIDs from target GDB (full table scan required) to <IDList> (comma separated string) and create a query for the source GDB WhereClause=”GlobalID NOT IN (<IDlist>)”.  In the source GDB only new records are read.